# Dialog onCancel method is being called when user press the screen

Tags: android, progressdialog

I have a progress dialog that has implemented onCancel method because i want to cancel it when the user press back key, but the problem is that when the user press on the screen, the dialog is being canceled, onCancel method is being called.

How can i avoid that?

This is the code:

```
public void showProgressDialog(Context ctx, String text_connecting) {
    if (this.progress == null) {
        this.progress = ProgressDialog.show(ctx, "", text_connecting, true,
                true);
        this.progress.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                hideProgressDialog();
            }
        });
    }
    this.progress.show();
}
```

Comment: You will have to check if the progress dialog is currently being displayed (In a thread), if displayed track the motion event in a thread. If motion event down while displaying set cancel-able to false. You can also use a local broadcast if you want to get rid of constant polling and keeping CPU busy.

Comment: One more solution would be to override your onBackPress. Set the dialog to non cancelable and on back press cancel it. That way your dialog wont be cancelled on touch event. Thats how it is and rightly so!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check if the progress dialog is currently being displayed (In a thread), if displayed track the motion event in a thread. If motion event down while displaying set cancel-able to false. You can also use a local broadcast if you want to get rid of constant polling and keeping CPU busy.

Something like:

```
@Override
        public void run() {


            if(progress.isShowing() &&(checkTheVariableYouSetInMotionEventDownHere){
                    progress.setCancellable(false); 
                         }
        }
    };
```

Its just a little hack, you can improve on the above logic more to make it fool proof.

Second way would be to check in motion event down itself and set cancelable false there.

Comment: wtf, thanks but i just want to show a simple cancelable dialog

Comment: One more solution would be to override your onBackPress. Set the dialog to non cancelable and on back press cancel it. That way your dialog wont be cancelled on touch event. Thats how it is and rightly so!

Comment: May be I misinterpreted your question, if you set the dialog to Dialog.cancelable(false) it will not cancel unless and until you call dialog.dismiss() on it.

Answer (score 0):

well, i finally solve it doing this insted of the previous code on my question

```
public boolean onKey(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent arg2) {
                    if (arg1 == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                        hideProgressDialog();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
this.progress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

This will prevent the `ProgressDialog` from being closed on any random touch of the screen. The back button will still cancel it though.

Answer (score 0):

use this code for reference look at this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCanceledOnTouchOutside%28boolean%29)

```
this.progress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```